# Overiding existing tag in storefront via AddOn doesn't work

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, add-on, storefront

I'm trying to make some changes in search and navigation product pages at storefront. For my modifications, I modified productListerGridItem.tag and productListerItem.tag, but nothing happens at storefront, I cant see my modifications.

The structure of my storefront tag folder after sync with addon:
[image]

(addon has been previously installed following basic instructions)

The tag must be used by searchresults gridcomponent.jsp cms component. I guess there is no need to explicitly modify the path to product taglib, shouldn't it work automatically? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You have to check in the jsp what is the path of the tag. For exemple : with `<product:productListerGridItem product="${product}" />`, check the product tag : `<%@ taglib prefix="product" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/product" %>` it won't look into your addons directory but in the responsive dir.